# hola me podrian decir como solucionar o como hacer que funcione

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, pycharm

mi problema es que quiero que tu ingreses los datos y se grafique una parabola pero mi codigo solo hace la grafica insertando los valores en el codigo y no se lo pide al usuario intente con un input pero nada me podrian ayudar porfavor

Es una parabola Trazado de parábola (y = x 2 )

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
numx = int(input("Escribe el numero x :"))
numy = int(input("Escribe el numero y :"))

y_cords = range(-60, 60)
x_cords = [x * x for x in y_cords]

plt.scatter(x_cords, y_cords)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Nunca especificas exactamente qué quieres, porque si el usuario te pasa un `numx` y un  `numy`, ¿qué quieres graficar de la parábola `y = x²`? ¿un solo punto? ¿Un rango? ¿Una parábola cuyo vértice esté en el punto recibido ? Nunca lo mencionas. Aclara tu pregunta porque tal como está, no tiene mucho sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

El problema es que no estas utilizando los valores que pides al usuario en ninguna parte

Para que la gráfica sea calculada en base a los números introducidos por el usuario debes utilizar `numx` y `numy` para calcular tus coordenadas

**Edición:** el valor `numx` no se estaba utilizando, ahora se usa como el punto de origen del eje x de la parábola

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
numx = int(input("Escribe el numero x :"))
numy = int(input("Escribe el numero y :"))

y_cords = range(-numy, numy+1)
x_cords = [(x * x) + numx for x in y_cords]

plt.scatter(x_cords, y_cords)
plt.show()
```

Comment: nunca usas la variable `numx` que contiene el valor ingresado por el input :/

Comment: Ah hahaha, cierto, eso pasa cuando se responde desde el baño haha. Ya lo cambié, gracias @Christian